# AngularJS ui-router conditional navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having troubles understanding how ui-router works. Trying to add a navigation to my app that shows/hides when a button is clicked.

```
.state('now', {
  url: '/now',
  views: {
    'content': {
      templateUrl: 'views/now',
      controller: 'MyCtrl'
    },
    'navigation': {
      templateUrl: 'views/navigation.html',
      controller: 'NavigationCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

I tried with a variable on rootScope, but that always shows the navigation. Adding class="ng-hide" will never show the navigation.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  ...
        <a id="menu-button" ng-click="show_navigation=!show_navigation"><i class="icon-reorder icon-2x"></i></a>
  ...
</nav>
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="show_navigation" id="nav-handler">
<nav id="nav" ng-if="show_navigation" ui-view="navigation"></nav>
```

Can I define the navigation as a state itself that can be rendered from all other views within the app?

Comment: As you have a lot of elements in your posted code that make no sense without the context or implementation, could you set up a Plunker or jsFiddle with your code which shows your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is related to the prototypical inheritance inherent in Javascript as applied to the `$rootScope` object.  What you can probably do is create an object in the run method for your module, and then set all of your flags to properties of that object.  As the properties are now stored on an object instead of primitives on `$rootScope`, when the various controllers prototype from `$rootScope`, they copy your flags by reference instead of by value, and changing them in one controller affects the display of a template run by another controller.  I would also use an `ng-show` directive instead of an `ng-if`.  It's a more efficient manipulation of the DOM as it is only adding a `display:none` style or not rather than removing or adding the entire DOM tree.